# Mapping composite key with Hibernate produces a raw field in Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, composite-key

-- **The Facts**....
In my project every class/table should have a couple (Site,Structure) in order to provide multisite deploy.

I provided an Installation class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COM_INSTALLATION")
@IdClass(InstallationPK.class)
public class Installation implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3601006283578715263L;

@Id
@Column(name = "site") 
private String site;
@Id
@Column(name = "structure")
private String structure;

/* ... constructor, getters, setters ... */
}
```

and its PK, as

```
public class InstallationPK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String site;
private String structure;
/* .. constructor, getters, setters ... */
}
```

then I have a MappedSuperclass named BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity
{
private Installation installation;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({    
    @JoinColumn(name = "site", referencedColumnName = "site"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "structure", referencedColumnName = "structure")
})
public Installation getInstallation() {
    return installation;
}
public void setInstallation(Installation installation) {
    this.installation = installation;
}
}
```

quite easy so far... every @Entity and @Table annotated class extending BaseEntity contains a column SITE, a column STRUCTURE and a related foreign key.
[image]

-- **The Problem**....
It happens that with a class implementing org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails and extending BaseEntity, Hibernate does not create the two columns but an INSTALLATION column with RAW type. That's the class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USR_USER", uniqueConstraints =    
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userId_seq_generator", sequenceName = "S_USER")
public class User  extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8698408700004341649L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "userId_seq_generator")
private Long userId;
/* ... getter, setters, ... */
}
```

and that's the result
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're mixing annotations on fields and on getters. Don't do that. Be consistent. Your OneToOne is probably ignored because it's on a getter whereas the @Id annotation is on a field.

Comment: thanks, I corrected that class, however that's not the point... even because it's working with the other cases

Comment: ops ... it was the point indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have point reputation to comment so i'll put here my comments:

Why instalationPK field isn't in instalation.class??
You should put `@EmbeddedId` in the field instalationPK in Installation.class.

I don't if makes differences, but put joinCollums on the field in `BaseEntity`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({    
    @JoinColumn(name = "site", referencedColumnName = "site"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "structure", referencedColumnName = "structure")
})
private Installation installation;
```

Comment: I'm not using @EmbeddedId because Installation class has @IdClass(InstallationPK.class)

Comment: anyway ... it is working in all the other classes extending BaseEntity... I believe it is concerned with UserDetails interface (or implementing an interface...)

Comment: I had not seen the @idClass...put the `UserDetails` interface. The other entities, they use other interface? which is?

Comment: the other classes don't extend any interface