# Hibernate: ManyToOne generating field raw(255)

Tags: database, hibernate, raw

I recently upgraded from  hibernate-core 4.1.7 to 5.0.9 and Have problem with this code:

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_AAA", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CS_BBB"))
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_CCC", columnNames = "FK_DDD")
    private ImportData importData;
```

This generate correct foreign columns pointing to the defining class, but also generating a column on the same class:
`IMPORTDATA RAW(255)`

Why is this raw(255) column generated ? I think it was not generated with Hibernate-core 4.1.7

any idea ?

Update 1: here is longer code fragments:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public abstract Long getId();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "IMPORT_DATA", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "UC_IMP_BID", columnNames = {"BUSINESS_ID"})
}, indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IDX_IMP_DGXML_ID", columnList = "FK_DGXML_ID"),
        @Index(name = "IDX_IMP_IMPXML_ID", columnList = "FK_IMPXML_ID")
})
public class ImportData extends BaseEntity { 

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
  public Long getId() { return id; } 
  // ... 

}



@Entity(name = "MUTATION")
@Table(name = "MUTATION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mutationsSeq", sequenceName = "MUTATIONS_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
public abstract class Mutation extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "mutationsSeq")
    private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_IMP_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CS_MUT_IMP_ID"))
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "IDX_MUT_IMP_ID", columnNames = "FK_IMP_ID")
    protected ImportData importData;

}


@Entity(name="XXX")
@DiscriminatorValue("XXX_DISC")
public class XXX extends Mutation {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that its generated due to this code snippet?

Comment: How does the identifier of the `ImportData` entity look like?

Comment: @SternK: yes, this is generated with the code snippet

Comment: @Christian: 
```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 public Long getId() { return id; }

Comment: I guess `ImportData` is missing `@Entity` or is not listed in your persistence context which results in it being treated as serializable type. On Oracle, it will use `raw(255)` for that type.

Comment: Can you show us the mapping of `ImportData`?

Comment: I added some code extract in my question as "edit 1", hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on [Mapping composite key with Hibernate produces a raw field in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196721/mapping-composite-key-with-hibernate-produces-a-raw-field-in-oracle):

I was mixing annotations on fields and methods. I also had @Id on an abstract superclass, and a redefinition on a derived class.

Fixing theses two elements, cleaning DB and regenerating in "create" ddl mode proved that the fix was no longer generating RAW field type.

Thanks for all your helps!